# Decoding mongodump's stderr

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, ubuntu, binary

I'm trying to mongodump my DB from my Node.js code:

```
var args = ['--db', 'DBName', '--out', backupDirectory];
        var mongodump = spawn('/usr/local/bin/mongodump', args);

        mongodump.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
           console.log(data);
        });
        mongodump.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        mongodump.on('exit', function (code: number) {
            console.log('mongodump exited with code ' + code);
        });
```

mongodump.stderr is reached. There, I get a byte array containing 155 bytes.

How can I decode the byte array into a readable message? What's the format that the stderr is encoded to?

Both the DB and my app run on the same machine whose OS is Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can try to use data.toString().